# How to list all models including a concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a simple way to list the class names of all models that include a particular Concern?

Something like:

```
ActiveRecord.models.select{ |m| m.included_modules.include? MyConcernModule }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have a concern named "Concerns::CoursePhotoable".  Here's the two models that include it:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.select{|c| \
     c.included_modules.include?(Concerns::CoursePhotoable)}.map(&:name)
=> ["Course", "ProviderCourse"]
```

To clarify, my concern is really named "Concerns::CoursePhotoable".  If yours was named "Fooable" you'd simply put "Fooable" where I have "Concerns::CoursePhotoable".  I namespace my concerns to avoid conflicts with say "Addressable".

EDIT: Current versions of Rails use `include?`. Older used `include`.

Comment: Thanks. I just took out the Concerns:: namespace

Comment: In Rails 4 (at least), it is **`include?`**, not `include`.

Comment: @AndreiHorak Thanks.  Interesting since the above worked with whatever version of Rails 4 I was running April 26.  Doesn't anymore though.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Hey, this statement is not working console. Any guesses?

Comment: Got it. All models are not loaded in the console in development mode. So before trying it out, run this statement

 Rails.application.eager_load!

Answer (score 4):

If it's your own Concern, you could add code to track when it's included:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module ChildTrackable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # keep track of what classes have included this concern:
  module Children
    extend self
    @included_in ||= []

    def add(klass)
      @included_in << klass
    end

    def included_in
      @included_in
    end
  end

  included do

    # track which classes have included this model concern
    Children.add self

  end

end

# access at:
ChildTrackable::Children.included_in
```

update: to eager load models prior:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

Comment: This gets messy in rails' development mode, when you make a change to `child_trackable.rb`, rails reloads it, and you lose the state of the module instance variable `included_in` :(

Comment: This also doesn't work if models are lazy loaded, which is typically the case.  Great idea though!